# What is $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=\lim_{x\to \infty}\int_{0}^{x}\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1-e^{-t-n}\right)dt-x+1$

Tags: integration, limits, gamma-function, products, constants

Working on the Gamma function I found the following:

Let

$$f(x)=\int_{0}^{x}\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1-e^{-t-n}\right)dt-x+1.$$

What is the limit

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=\,?$$

As possible guess it's near by the absissa of the minimum for the factorial function which is $x\simeq 0.4616$.

Question:

Does it admits a closed form?

Comment: The graph for the product seems similar to $\frac{\sin(\pi e^{\frac{-x}{2}})}{\pi (1-e^{-x})}e^{\frac{x}{2}}$ in the domain $x \in [0, \infty)$.
With an error of 0.0003
[Desmos Link](https://imgur.com/a/jhZgrgS)

Answer (score 3):

Not a closed form, but a rapidly (i.e. quadratically) convergent series, worth noting:
$$\color{blue}{1-\frac1{e-1}+\frac1{2(e-1)(e^2-1)}-\frac1{3(e-1)(e^2-1)(e^3-1)}+\dots}$$
Indeed, we're evaluating $1-I(e^{-1})$ where, in [this notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-Pochhammer_symbol), $$I(q)=\int_0^\infty\big(1-(qe^{-t};q)_\infty\big)\,dt=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n-1}\frac{q^{n(n+1)/2}}{n(q;q)_n}$$ after using a series for $(x;q)_\infty$ from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-Pochhammer_symbol#Identities), and termwise integration.

Answer (score 2):

$$f(x)=(1-x)+\int_0^x \frac{e^t}{e^t-1} \left(e^{-t};\frac{1}{e}\right){}_{\infty }\,\,dt$$ does not seem to have a closed form.

Numerically, the convergence is quite fast
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
x & f(x) \\
 10 & 0.4620257654385160639655594317 \\
 15 & 0.4619995218587963453456974771 \\
 20 & 0.4619993450303188952646355559 \\
 25 & 0.4619993438388579577552602090 \\
 30 & 0.4619993438308299571055464707 \\
 35 & 0.4619993438307758648626600170 \\
 40 & 0.4619993438307755003919943864 \\
 45 & 0.4619993438307754979362103587 \\
 50 & 0.4619993438307754979196634161 \\
 55 & 0.4619993438307754979195519237 \\
 60 & 0.4619993438307754979195511724 \\
 65 & 0.4619993438307754979195511669 \\
 70 & 0.4619993438307754979195511671 \\
 75 & 0.4619993438307754979195511673 \\
 \end{array}
\right)$$

Nothing found using inverse symbolic calculators (interesting are the two expressions above and below this value in the $ISC$).

Comment: So the limit is $$
1 + \int_0^{ + \infty } {\left[ {\frac{{{\rm e}^t }}{{{\rm e}^t  - 1}}({\rm e}^{ - t} ;{\rm e}^{ - 1} )_\infty   - 1} \right]{\rm d}t}  = 1 + \int_0^1 {\left[ {\frac{{(t;{\rm e}^{ - 1} )_\infty  }}{{1 - t}} - 1} \right]\frac{{{\rm d}t}}{t}} .
$$

Comment: @Gary. The problem is numerical. If you make the upper bound $(1-10^{-k})$, you need $k=31$ o get $30$ exact decimal places.

Answer (score 1):

$\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1-e^{-t-n}\right)$ has its roots at $t=-n, t \in (-\infty, -1]$

Also
$$\sin(x) = x\prod_{n=1}^\infty \left(1-\frac{x^2}{n^2\pi^2}\right)$$

$$\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{\pi x} = \prod_{n=1}^\infty \left(1-\frac{x^2}{n^2}\right)$$

$$\frac{\sin(\pi e^{\frac{-x}{2}})}{\pi}e^{\frac{x}{2}} = \prod_{n=1}^\infty \left(1-\frac{e^{-x}}{n^2}\right)$$
The last problem seems to be how to convert $n^{2}$ to $e^n$.
This is probably a modification of a infinite product, I found some similarities with the $\sin(x)$ one but it didnot work out in the end.